# How to add jarray Object into JObject

Tags: c#, asp.net, json.net

How to add `JArray` into `JObject`?  I am getting an exception when changing the `jarrayObj` into `JObject`.

```
parameterNames = "Test1,Test2,Test3";

JArray jarrayObj = new JArray();

foreach (string parameterName in parameterNames)
{
    jarrayObj.Add(parameterName);
}

JObject ObjDelParams = new JObject();
ObjDelParams["_delete"] = jarrayObj;

JObject UpdateAccProfile = new JObject(
                               ObjDelParams,
                               new JProperty("birthday", txtBday),
                               new JProperty("email", txtemail))
```

I need output in this form:

```
{
    "_delete": ["Test1","Test2","Test3"],
    "birthday":"2011-05-06",          
    "email":"dude@test.com" 
}
```

Answer (score 49):

I see two problems with your code as you posted it.

1. `parameterNames` needs to be an array of strings, not just a single string with commas.
2. You can't add a `JArray` directly to a `JObject`; you have to put it in a `JProperty` and add *that* to the `JObject`, just like you are doing with the "birthday" and "email" properties.

Corrected code:

```
string[] parameterNames = new string[] { "Test1", "Test2", "Test3" };

JArray jarrayObj = new JArray();

foreach (string parameterName in parameterNames)
{
    jarrayObj.Add(parameterName);
}

string txtBday = "2011-05-06";
string txtemail = "dude@test.com";

JObject UpdateAccProfile = new JObject(
                               new JProperty("_delete", jarrayObj),
                               new JProperty("birthday", txtBday),
                               new JProperty("email", txtemail));

Console.WriteLine(UpdateAccProfile.ToString());
```

Output:

```
{
  "_delete": [
    "Test1",
    "Test2",
    "Test3"
  ],
  "birthday": "2011-05-06",
  "email": "dude@test.com"
}
```

Also, for future reference, if you are getting an exception in your code, it is helpful if you say in your question exactly what the exception is, so that we don't have to guess.  It makes it easier for us to help you.

Comment: Great answer! Also`foreach` is not really necessary in the original code, `JArray`s constructor accepts array of objects as argument.

Answer (score 10):

```
// array of animals
var animals = new[] { "cat", "dog", "monkey" };

// our profile object
var jProfile = new JObject
        {
            { "birthday", "2011-05-06" },
            { "email", "dude@test.com" }
        };

// Add the animals to the profile JObject
jProfile.Add("animals", JArray.FromObject(animals));

Console.Write(jProfile.ToString());
```

Outputs:

```
{    
  "birthday": "2011-05-06",
  "email": "dude@test.com",
  "animals": [
    "cat",
    "dog",
    "monkey"
  ]
}
```

Answer (score 2):

```
var jObject = new JObject();
jObject.Add("birthday", "2011-05-06");
jObject.Add("email", "dude@test.com");
var items = new [] { "Item1", "Item2", "Item3" };
var jSonArray = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(items);
var jArray = JArray.Parse(jSonArray);
jObject.Add("_delete", jArray);
```

Comment: It would help readers if you add some context to your answer.

Comment: exactly what i was looking for.

Answer (score 2):

it is easy,

```
JArray myarray = new JArray();
JObject myobj = new JObject();
// myobj.add(myarray); -> this is wrong. you can not add directly.

JProperty subdatalist = new JProperty("MySubData",myarray);
myobj.Add(subdata); // this is the correct way I suggest.
```