# I want to know the type of this value and how can I use it?

Tags: c#, json, rgba

I'm creating a SDK for Camtasia, and I'm looking at this file with this piece of code:

```
"backgroundColor" : [239, 0, 191, 255]
```

Of course, I need to do more than this, but this is basically what I'm doing.
I need to create the same thing but with c#. I cannot do this because it gives me an error:

```
jobject.Add("backgroundColor", [239, 0, 191, 255]);
```

But when I wrap the value around quotes, when I convert it to a string, the value is wrapped around double quotes like this:

```
"backgroundColor" : "[239, 0, 191, 255]"
```

But I can't have the value wrapped around double quotes because Camtasia can't read it, it needs it outside double quotes.

Can anyone help?
I'll be glad to provide additional information if needed.

Comment: what precisely should your program do though?

Comment: My program should create a file that can be opened in Camtasia. @RenéCarannante

Comment: JObject timeline = new JObject();
            timeline.Add("id", 1);
            timeline.Add("backgroundColor", "[3, 35, 255, 6]"); Hope this helps @xTwisteDx

Comment: then best use a conventional JSON writer instead of doing your own hacky JSON converter also it will safe you a lo of time and headake. I suggest you take a look at [Json.Net]http://james.newtonking.com/projects/json-net.aspx

Comment: I would use jobject.ToString(); is it recommended to use that? @RenéCarannante

Comment: This app is going to create a huge JSON file, so I'm hoping I won't need to do that @xTwisteDx

Comment: EXACTLY what I need. I totally forgot about JArrays. Thank you @xTwisteDx

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use a JArray

```
string[] parameterNames = new string[] { "Test1", "Test2", "Test3" };

    JArray jarrayObj = new JArray();

    foreach (string parameterName in parameterNames)
    {
        jarrayObj.Add(parameterName);
    }
```

Comment: Thank you for the recommendation, that thing was troubling me alot.

Answer (score 0):

When you are wrapping with "" - you are passing a string.
You need to pass array:

```
jobject.Add("backgroundColor", new int[]{ 239, 0, 191, 255 });
```

Comment: I'm getting this error in Visual Studio, "Argument 2: cannot convert from 'int[]' to 'Newtonsoft.Json.Linq.JToken'"

Comment: Sorry, was writing it from phone, and did not check that it compiles. I think solution is described here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19634153/how-to-add-jarray-object-into-jobject